# Why prop data update in vue template, but not in javascript part

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, prop

my `{{this.topic}}` in the template section is update when its value in parent component is change, but the same value in the script part just keep remain the first value it get at `search_params.set('param1', this.topic);`, nothing wrong with other part of code, everything work fine. Yo can try it out here http://jsfiddle.net/6gk13sep/1/

For anyone who wonder how the out put should be, when you try to press the other button, the app should re-request the API with that button name

```
 Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
  breedKey: {{ breedKey }}
  <br />
  topic: {{ this.topic }}
  <br />
  API DATA TEST: {{ this.point0 }}
  </div>
  `,
  props: ["breedKey", "time"],
  computed: {
    topic() {
      return this.breedKey;
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      point0: [],
      point1: [],
      point2: [],
    };
  },

  async created() {

    try {

      var url = new URL('https://www.mustavi.com/TimeSeries/?param1=China&param2=00');
      var search_params = url.searchParams;

      // new value of param set to my topic
      search_params.set('param1', this.topic);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only calling the API in `created`. Updates to your props won't trigger it again.

You need to [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) `breed` and make your API call in the watch method.

```
watch: {
  async breedKey (oldVal, newVal) {
     // created method code
  }
}
```

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pkLryqc/4/) to see this working.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is basically a correct answer! You need to watch `breedKey` instead of course

Answer (score 0):

just add v-if="breedKey" to child component will solve your problem. as show below:

```
<child v-if="breedKey" v-bind:breed-key="breedKey" v-bind:time="time"> </child>
```

the reason is when the child component "created" hook was called, the topic(breedKey) from parent component was not been get its value yet. v-if directive make the child component lazy init until "breedKey" get it's value from parent component.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/yangjunjun/z49wak5v/1/

Comment: oh, thank for your edit, but my actual goal is when I press the button with other name, it resent the API whit that button name, API in this edit is still the same when I press the button